# Using AC rated thermostat to control DC current? Hope to use an AC rated thermostat to switch a DC current into a solar charge controller

Tags: switching-transients

I need to turn off solar input ,DC, when battery box gets below freezing.  I can only find AC rated remote bulb thermostats for this as they do not use battery energy for switching.  Switching current could be up to 20amps DC at 96 volts.  Doing this protects my lithium batteries from accidental low temp charging damage?

Comment: DC is more demanding on the switch contacts. If it is rated to switch DC, then the DC current will be much lower than the AC current rating. You will need a relay or contactor.

Comment: Why don't you use the solar input supply to warm up your batteries a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely you'll be able to find a thermostat rated to directly switch that current at that voltage. DC current is considerably more difficult to interrupt than AC current at ~100VDC. For example, a 10A 250VAC switch may be rated (if it's rated at all) at 0.6A @ 125VDC (usually low voltage DC is okay at full rating up to maybe 30VDC).

You can use an appropriately rated solid-state relay or contactor and switch that with the thermostat.